# Check two times falls between two times python

Tags: python

Want to check whether two times falls in between to another to time

Checking time is between `start=2 pm` and `end=3 pm`

```
ex :1
t1=12 PM
T2=2.30 PM
```

here  `0.5 hours` falls in that time

---

```
ex :2
t1=2.0 pm
t2=4 pm
```

here `1 hours` fall in that time

---

```
ex : 3 
t1=12
t2=5pm
```

here `2 hours` fall in that time

I want the code to check whether t1 and t2 falls in between start and end

Comment: What code do you have currently? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Your examples don't make sense: you mention "here 0.5 hours falls in that time", but which "0.5 hours" do you mean?

Comment: It seems you want to search for overlaps between time intervals, not whether (a) time(s) falls between to two timestamps.

Comment: if two times are 12 pm and 2.30 pm . then  we have 0.5 between 2 and 3 pm

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong since I got confused by your question. But based on how I understand it, you simply want to know whether two times fall in between two other times.

Try to use the [DateTime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module in Python like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

# Start time
start = time(hour=14, minute=0)  # 2 PM

# End time
end = time(hour=15, minute=0)  # 3 PM

# Check if time1 falls in the range
time1 = time(hour=12, minute=0)  # 12 PM
if start <= time1 <= end:
    print("Time1 falls in the range")
else:
    print("Time1 does not fall in the range")

# Check if time2 falls in the range
time2 = time(hour=14, minute=30)  # 2:30 PM
if start <= time2 <= end:
    print("Time2 falls in the range")
else:
    print("Time2 does not fall in the range")

# Check if time3 falls in the range
time3 = time(hour=16, minute=0)  # 4 PM
if start <= time3 <= end:
    print("Time3 falls in the range")
else:
    print("Time3 does not fall in the range")
```

This code will check whether each of the three times (time1, time2, and time3) falls in the range between start and end. The output will be:

```
Time1 does not fall in the range
Time2 falls in the range
Time3 does not fall in the range
```